# Open OracleConnection ONGet and Close it OnPost .NET6 webapp

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I ve been struggling with stateless http request for days on my razpr .NET6 webapp

My razor page has a button that opens a modal, this triggers a method (with ajax)

```
 public OracleConnection connection { get; set; }

 public OracleTransaction transaction { get; set; }
public JsonResult OnPostGetOrder(string order)
        {
            connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();//
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
....}
```

The connection should remain opened until the modal is closed or the form inside it is cancelled.

So I need to get connection and transaction values in the following method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCloseModal()
        {
            connection.close()
            transaction.Rollback();
...

}
```

Of course it won't work because of http being stateless, so connection being null

Here are all my attempt and none of it worked:

1. [tempdata] public oracleconnection connection
   doesn't work because razor cannot store oracleconn inside tempdata
2. [bindproperty] public oracleconnection connection with @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.connection) or  don't work: the OnpostClose doesn't just trigger
3. _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["Connection"] = connection; I have no idea what should I use to retrieve its value because VS2022 refuse the following: HttpContext.Session.Get("Connection"); HttpContext.Session["connection"]; HttpContext.session.Get("Connection") ; HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("connection",OracleConnection);
4. store connection and transaction in javascript then sending it back to server but Ajax s not able to pass oracleconnection to C# parameter (closeModal function doesn't trigger)

Please tell me there is something I can use to do this trivial task

Comment: Why do you feel the need to start the transaction in `OnGet`? The usual pattern in a web application is to do this kind of thing when data is posted back to the server. Otherwise what you wan to achieve - maintaining a live database connection between the browser and the server is not possible.

Comment: Because I have a select for update nowait which should blocks any transaction trying to select for update nowait the same row. the 'blocking' stops when the transaction ends  (in my case when the modal closes)

Comment: HTTP is stateless, so the state of the connection and the transaction is not stored between HTTP requests. To store the connection and transaction across requests, you need to use a persistence mechanism like sessions. You can use the ASP.NET Core's ISession interface to store the connection and transaction in a session.

Comment: What if the modal never closes because e.g. the browser crashes? You should consider implementing an alternative concurrency strategy that is better suited to stateless web applications.

Comment: I d like to use another strategy but any change in the database trigger an irreversible action in another program.